# API Access Using SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, rails-api

```
Server: 
  Ubuntu 14.04
  Apache2
  SSL enabled
  Rails 3.2 Application
```

I have SSL implemented, using a self-generated certificate.

I have a REST API implemented as part of the Rails application (for a limited set of REST calls). I can call the API fine, using curl, and the http url end point.

When I try using the https end point, I get no response.

I tested https access to the application, from a web browser, and that's working fine, although the browser give me a warning, that the site is not safe.

Any ideas?

Comment: "although the browser give me a warning, that the site is not safe." : self signed certificates are generally shown as insecure by browsers and will not be recognized by default by clients such as `curl` or `wget` where you will need to either disable X.509 certificates verification (bad, do not do that) or specifically add your self signed certificate as a trusted one. Also simpler solution: use Let's Encrypt, free certificates that will work everywhere and be recognized.

Comment: I ended up getting a certificate from letsencrypt and it's working. If you turn this into an answer, I will give you credit for it.